# How can I enhance the quality of images generated from PDF?

Tags: pdf, typo3, ghostscript, graphicsmagick, typo3-9.x

We use `TYPO3 9.5.13`, `GraphicsMagick 1.3.29`, `Ghostscript 9.27`, `BK2K\\BootstrapPackage 11.0.1`

Using PDFs as normal images is no problem.
But now I want a 'preview' of the PDFs in full column width (~1000px). And although the PDF has a high resolution, the generated Image has a width of 595px only and any text is nearly unreadable.

The problem occurs with Image-CEs like in the uploads CE, which I want to enhance:
each time I want the image using the full column width it renders in a bad resolution and the image seems distorted.

here a small area from the generated image:
[image]

and the same area from the PDF as shown in PDF-reader:
[image]

The fluid part:

```
<img loading="lazy" 
     src="{f:uri.image(image: file, cropVariant: 'default', maxWidth: 1100)}" 
     width="{bk2k:lastImageInfo(property: 'width')}" 
     height="{bk2k:lastImageInfo(property: 'height')}" 
     intrinsicsize="{bk2k:lastImageInfo(property: 'width')}x{bk2k:lastImageInfo(property: 'height')}" 
     title="{file.properties.title}" 
     alt="{file.properties.alternative}">
```

which results in something like:

```
<img loading="lazy" 
     src="/fileadmin/_processed_/3/2/csm_Warum_D-Arzt_6afd8ad8d4.png"
     intrinsicsize="595x842" 
     title="" 
     alt="" 
     width="595" 
     height="842">
```

---

Edit:

In case of using this FLUID:

```
<img loading="lazy" 
     src="{f:uri.image(image: file, cropVariant: 'default', width: 1100)}" 
     width="{bk2k:lastImageInfo(property: 'width')}" 
     height="{bk2k:lastImageInfo(property: 'height')}" 
     intrinsicsize="{bk2k:lastImageInfo(property: 'width')}x{bk2k:lastImageInfo(property: 'height')}" 
     title="{file.properties.title}" 
     alt="{file.properties.alternative}">
```

I get:

```
<img loading="lazy" 
     src="/fileadmin/_processed_/3/2/csm_Warum_D-Arzt_2ffb63b15f.png" 
     intrinsicsize="1100x1557" 
     title="" 
     alt="" 
     width="1100" 
     height="1557">
```

the image is bigger (and overflow the container) but the quality is worse the same, notice the bigger pixels:

[image]

Comment: 595? That sounds a bit like there is a maxwidth defined in the constants?

Comment: Are you using the standard CEs? There is a maxGalleryWidth=600 in TS settings. 595px sounds a bit like these 600px minus a few paddings/borders/...

Comment: I use the CEs from bootstrapPackage. I can't find any settings `maxGalleryWidth` or any value `595` or `600` (except colordefinitions).

Comment: I do not know the bootstrap package, so I can't say, if this is something specific to that ext. You can analyze all constants in the TypoScript Object Browser (choose template module and then TypoScript Object Browser in the upper dropdown). You get a list with all constants which take effect. Something set under styles.content.textmedia for example?
Another possibility: as a PDF does not have image dimensions like a real image, please try to replace maxWidth with width.

Comment: Just to narrow down the sources of error: does the same happen if you attach a large image file instead a PDF file? If so, this is a TYPO3 setting and has nothing to do with Graphicsmagick or Ghostscript

Comment: question enhanced with usage of `width` instead of `maxWidth`.

Comment: bigger JPGs are rendered as high as possible, meaning: no artefacts like with PDFs.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce this. My thoughts: PDFs behave in a different way that images do (other dimensions and measurements). So in this case, TYPO3 / GM renders a smaller image, scaling it to a bigger size. I played with the density parameter here locally and could improve the quality. So maybe you can help yourself with a viewhelper, generating your own thumbnail using CommandUtility::imageMagickCommand with your own arguments and a higher density level?

Comment: can you make an answer with instructions how to enhance the density parameter?

Comment: Another thought: I had similar strange quality problems while using GIFBUILDER. Solution was setting ['GFX']['gdlib_png'] => true. Without this setting somewhen while converting the image, it is converted to a GIF (=bad quality image).

Comment: And: png_truecolor should also be true. Not sure, if this is still in v9, but at least in v8 it still was there. If not set, png thumbnails are used with setting above, but only using 256 colors, resulting in a gif-like behaviour. (see png8/png24)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a PDF is **NOT** an image. It is a container format which can contain vectors and images with different colorspaces and dimensions. A bitmap image has fixed dimensions width, height, density, a PDF not. Originally, it was created and optimized to work for printers, not for screens.

TYPO3 reflects that with a message in the backend:
[image]

IMHO, there is no perfect way of handling PDFs to behave like images, as you know the output format, but not the input format (properly). Two ways to get acceptable results:

1. Extend content elements or create new ones and add a second image slot for PDF preview images. Create the preview images yourself with a graphical program.
2. Write your own viewhelper and create your own thumbnails

Solution 1 will lead to more work for editors. Would be no best practise for me.

---

I would go with an own viewhelper.

**Add your own render type for PDFs:**

```
<f:switch expression="{file.type}">
  <f:case value="5">
    <f:render partial="Media/Type/Pdf" arguments="{file: file, dimensions: dimensions, data: data, settings: settings}" />
  </f:case>
  <f:defaultCase>
    <f:render partial="Media/Type/Image" arguments="{file: file, dimensions: dimensions, data: data, settings: settings}" />
  </f:defaultCase>
</f:switch>
```

**Partial Media/Type/Pdf**

```
{namespace cv=Conversion\HelperUtils\ViewHelpers}
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" xmlns:ce="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/FluidStyledContent/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
  <cv:forEachPdfThumbnail document="{file}" pages="1" as="pdfPreviewPage">
    <f:image src="{pdfPreviewPage}" alt="" />
  </cv:forEachPdfThumbnail>
</html>
```

**ViewHelper:**

This viewhelper convert multiple pages from a PDF, using the CommandUtility::imageMagickCommand. You can raise the density to a higher value to improve quality. 
As mentioned, this viewhelper was developed a few years ago and could be improved (e.g. saving to fileadmin/*processed* instead of typo3temp. Feel free to clone and improve: https://github.com/conversion1/t3-pdfthumbnailviewhelper/blob/master/ForEachPdfThumbnailViewHelper.php

```
public static function renderStatic(array $arguments, \Closure $renderChildrenClosure, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext)
{

    $templateVariableContainer = $renderingContext->getVariableProvider();

    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference $document */
    $document = $arguments['document'];
    $pages = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $arguments['pages']));

    $colorspace = TRUE === isset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['colorspace']) ? $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['colorspace'] : 'RGB';
    $absFilePath = GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName($document->getOriginalFile()->getPublicUrl());
    $destinationPath = 'typo3temp/';
    $destinationFilePrefix = 'pdf-prev_' . $document->getOriginalFile()->getNameWithoutExtension();
    $destinationFileExtension = 'png';

    $output = '';

    foreach ($pages as $pageNumber) {

        if($pageNumber > 0) {
            $pageNumber = intval($pageNumber);
        } else {
            $pageNumber = 1;
        }

        $destinationFileSuffix =  '_page-' . $pageNumber;
        $absDestinationFilePath = GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName($destinationPath . $destinationFilePrefix . $destinationFileSuffix . '.' . $destinationFileExtension);

        $imgArguments = '-colorspace ' . $colorspace;
        $imgArguments .= ' -density 300';
        $imgArguments .= ' -sharpen 0x.6';
        $imgArguments .= ' "' . $absFilePath . '"';
        $imgArguments .= '['. intval($pageNumber - 1) .']';
        $imgArguments .= ' "' . $absDestinationFilePath . '"';

        if(!file_exists($absDestinationFilePath)) {
            $command = CommandUtility::imageMagickCommand('convert', $imgArguments);
            CommandUtility::exec($command);
        }

        $thumbnail = substr($absDestinationFilePath, strlen(Environment::getPublicPath()));
        $templateVariableContainer->add($arguments['as'], $thumbnail);
        $output .= $renderChildrenClosure();
        $templateVariableContainer->remove($arguments['as']);

    }

    return $output;
}
```

---

Edit:

A third way: You can use a JavaScript library to generate thumbnails on the fly. E.g. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js